# UITextField Secure Text Font Size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have an password `UITextField`, for that i have given **SecureText** to **YES**. Now when i type the characters font is too small like [image]

After touching outside of that `UITextField` the Font of text changes and looks like,
[image]

I need a consistency  in the font, what is the property to fix this.

Comment: You can set the font size in IB

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi : I have set font size in IB as 13 for this textfield. But when editing time it shows some font and at non-editing time it looks big.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: I have just created a Outlet of textfield thats all..!! have not done anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField.secureTextEntry)
    {
        [textField setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:10.0]];
    }
}
```